# Sample django and python project

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to python and its framework Django. I am learning both the technologies parallel from its documentation, so I thought if there are some projects which I can use as reference for learning then it will help me learn the things fast. Can someone suggest me any such links.

Comment: You could install it by following [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/install/) or [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/) and make your own sample with [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that you learn Python well, really well, since django uses Python's myriad of features to almost their fullest extent. I would start off with any random Python tutorial, but Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way is the best, and you can find a free HTML version of what he wrote. You can then get a book that teaches you to make games (great way to learn); [Invent your own games with Python](http://inventwithpython.com/chapters/).

Well since you're a newbie, you'll probably want to start off by making a blog or something and then slowly moving up and making more complicated websites. The best approach to learning django is to first make something simple, then look at other people's code and learn from that. You an pick up a lot from reading other people's code and how they've structured their logic.

For a free resource, I would check out [Mike Hibbert's Django tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD) on YouTube. He teaches you pretty much everything. Don't worry about the IDE he is using, just use a text editor like Sublime Text 2.

After you've made your simple website, its best that you start reading a book called Two Scoops of Django, by Daniel Greenfield. Really good tips and tricks on how to use django right. Great for newbies.

After that, start reading code. Read other people's code and understand how they made their sites. You can take a look at many sample django projects on the web. I would suggest that you go over to github and just randomly search for django projects. Thats what I did, and I think looking at other people's code is the best way to learn.

Lastly, if you want to get even more into django, join the IRC. Great bunch of guys there, not as lively as the Rails bunch, but they're pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Games Brainiac..I wanted the exact answer what you have posted. Coz even I feel the same that best way of mastering something new is to go through the existing works. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Seconding the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). It really is one of the most comprehensive and easy-to-follow framework tutorials out there. By the time you've finished it you'll have a much greater understanding of how all the django pieces fit together. It also has plenty of room to expand so you can experiment with new ideas.

Completing the tutorial has an added benefit: the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) frequently refers back to the tutorial app in its examples. So having the tutorial project available means you can quickly try out the features you're reading up on in an actual project.

One of the things that I (and possibly most people that are new to python as well as django) struggled with was separating "what bits are python?" from "what bits are django?". There's no real quick-fix for this other than gaining experience but like another answer mentioned, learning python on the side (maybe doing a few projects just using python) can help you with writing clean code within django too, and also see what is "missing" without django.

Answer (score 1):

First start with Python as indicated.

Then, with regard to Django: I learnt a lot from the http://www.gettingstartedwithdjango.com/ video series, especially on set up and interesting packages to use. 
No need to watch the video if you don't want to, as everything is outlined below the video as well.

Next to that, http://www.effectivedjango.com is a great help.